# How to implement File Update logic in Chunk Processing (Java Batch - JSR352)

Tags: java, batch-file, websphere-liberty, jsr352, java-batch

I am trying to develop a Java batch program using the IBM's JSR352 Implementation. Since the batch job involves iteratively processing huge number of records, I chose to implement it as Chunk Processing job.

This job involves of 3 steps which keeps repeated for each records in File 1

1. Reader Class:  Read content from File 1 to form a key text
2. Processor Class: Look-up the Key text in File 2
3. Writer Class: Update the text in File 2 where key text was found with a custom text

> From the processor to writer, I can return all line numbers where the 
>   key text matches were found. But, without RandomAccess to file, how 
>   can i update those specific line numbers in File 2 from my Writer?

***Since I am restricted to use only [these Input/Outputstreams](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.71.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/FileFactory.html#newBufferedWriter(java.lang.String)) for
 file handling I am unable to split the Lookup & Update logic between
 processor & writer classes. How can i achieve this ?***

This is because the code will be developed in a windows machine but, finally executed in a mainframe (z/os) server.

Answer (score 1):

The processor is technically optional, so you could merge the lookup/update logic in just the writer class.  That might help.

On z/OS this is easier to do with a VSAM dataset (also accessible via the JZOS ZFile APIs).  But that's going to be hard to develop/test on Windows.  I suppose you could keep the ZFile calls separate and on Windows replace them with some rigged up emulation that would work well enough for testing purposes.

Comment: i thought about merging the lookup and update logic but, will it anyway impact the periodic commit feature taken care by the container (driven by the "item-count" commit interval property defined at chunk level) ?

Comment: As long as the reader returns a non-null the container increments the item-count.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had to drop the JZOS FileFactory based approach and use the JZOS ZFile's locate API to find the the specific lines (using keys) and update it from the writer.